# Освещение и окантовка в OpenGL

Tags: opengl, 3d

Хотелось бы нарисовать что-то типа такого кубика:

[image]

Возникают следующие вопросы:

1. Как сделать один элемент? (например угловой)

   1.a. Каким образом можно нарисовать куб с закруглённой кромкой? (желательно, чтобы параметр закруглённости можно было задавать). Отдельно создать в редакторе не вариант, т.к. элементы, в зависимости от входных параметров, будут генерироваться разных размеров (не все 1х1х1, как тут)

   1.b. Как дать понять, что чёрная основа должна отражать свет, а наклейки нет? (Их нужно будет создавать и прорисовывать, как отдельные плоские объекты?)

---

2. Минимальная структура хранения элемента:

   2.a. Относительные(относительно центра куба) координаты элемента (x;y;z)

   2.b. Поворот элемента относительно начального положения (tx;ty;tz)

   2.c. Цвет наклейки на каждой грани в начальном положении (чтобы не нужно было о них думать при вращении, а можно было вычислить в любое время с учётом поворота относительно начального положения)

---

этого вроде должно хватить...

Comment: Слишком много вопросов в одном, разделите их на несколько

Comment: В общем случае вам нужна 3д модель маленького кубика. Для разных цветов, использовать разные текстуры. Отрисовать этот маленький кубик N раз, чтобы получить кубик с картинки. Использовать шейдер с освещением и настроить материал, чтобы был блик.

Comment: @Unick, вместо `Отрисовать этот маленький кубик N раз` можно использовать geometry instancing.

Comment: @Unick, а как я и написал в пункте 1. a. все элементы будут разного размера, придётся этот маленький кубик растягивать постоянно по разным осям?

Comment: @Arhad точнее не все, а некоторые...  Т.е. будут некоторые элементы сдвоенные/встроенные и т.д. Но geometry instancing, возможно, всё-таки использовать получится, надо о ней подробнее почитать, разобраться

Comment: @Isaev, instancing — это когда для некоторых вершинных атрибутов правило «одно значение на одну вершину» заменяется на «одно значение на N автоматически выполняемых проходов визуализации (порождающих N копий одной и той же геометрии)». Тогда, если все «элементы» являются параллелепипедами, можно ввести по-instance-овый параметр «растягивание по X/Y/Z» для размножаемого кубика-базы «элемента».